How should I proceed when the only answer references a highly technical resource I don't understand?
I recently asked this question Why are different operations in mathematics referred to as "convolution"?, and the only answer provided references to a very technical book on 'Fourier Analysis on Groups'. However, I find myself unfamiliar with the prerequisites for understanding the resource.
I have studied mathematics at the undergraduate level, but this topic seems to require advanced knowledge in areas such as

Abstract algebra
Functional analysis

How should I approach this situation? Is it appropriate to ask for a simpler explanation or references with more accessible prerequisites?
Also what about the answer, should I accept that or leave it  not accepted?
I want to ensure I learn efficiently while respecting the community guidelines.

Did you also look at the resources/suggestions linked to/described in the comments?

Offering a bounty will bring your question to the attention of more people, who may give you a more accessible answer.

@JyrkiLahtonen Yes I did it when saw the answer.

[Comment upgraded to answer]
You are certainly within your rights to point out that the answer that has been posted is well above your pay grade, and to express your hope that someone will be able to post an answer you can understand. Now, I'm not familiar with the area; it's possible that there is no way to answer your question without recourse to very advanced topics. I know this happens frequently in Number Theory, where questions any child can understand have answers worthy of Fields medals. So you might be out of luck. As to whether to accept the answer, that is entirely up to you.
